# GCC preprocessor MACRO definition (-D) doesn't work

Tags: c, gcc

In makefile I have this

```
VERSION = 1.5
```

and in the command line this is passed to **gcc**

```
-DVERSION=$(VERSION)
```

In the code there is this

```
#define APP_VERSION VERSION
#define STRINGIFY(X)    #X
```

and this:

```
fprintf(executionLog, "Application Name - v" STRINGIFY(APP_VERSION) "\n");
```

but in the *executionLog* log file I find this:

```
Application Name - vAPP_VERSION
```

Why this happens?

Compiler --> **Mingw32 on Windows installed with MSYS2**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to expand the argument first and then stringify it, you need an extra indirection, try this:

```
#define APP_VERSION VERSION
#define STRINGIFY(X)    STRINGIFY1(X)
#define STRINGIFY1(X)    #X
...
fprintf(executionLog, "Application Name - v" STRINGIFY(APP_VERSION) "\n");
```

Comment: It works but I don't understand the logic behind this. How it works?

Comment: @Francesco ["damage to your sanity can quickly result"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cppinternals/Macro-Expansion.html) -- I wouldn't try looking for some simple logical explanation, it just does

Comment: @Francesco or more accurately this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing <- "argument is substituted once, as-is"